# Can't seem to adjust pic to fit the screen

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me work this out?

[**screenshoot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr6vw.jpg**screen**)

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: You can try background-size: cover the only issue with that is that it will crop the image if the aspect ratio doesn't match. You should also provide us with the HTML so be easier to help you

Answer (score 2):

There may be more than one reason for this.

- The natural width value of your image is smaller than the area you want it to occupy. (max-width) doesn't solve this.
- The element surrounding the picture has a fixed or maximum height value. The picture has reached this height and cannot grow any further. (In short, the mismatched aspect ratio)

**The most natural solution for this,**

### If you use the image with the `<img src =' .. '/>` element

CSS `object-fit: cover;` will use feature.

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
    /* add */ object-fit: cover;
}
```

### If you use the image with the `background-image:` or `background:` property

CSS `background-size: cover;` will use feature.

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
    /* add */ background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I can tell I'm outdated, is object-fit the modified version of background-size?

Comment: Actually no. One works for the `background`, the other works for the `<img />` element itself.

Comment: Right ok, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: I assumed that in this case `<img />` was used. In fact, it would be correct to add both possibilities.

Comment: Yea, I actually agree, adding the second one has an option since he might be using background-image I guess

Comment: I made it as transparent as possible: D

Comment: Clear as day light :P